# What oil brand, style, weight, and filter for a 230k 98 Honda Acord LX 4-cyl?

Tags: oil-change, sparkplugs, oil-filter

first time here and pointed this way by a friend after I asked about on twitter.

I've got a 1998 Honda Accord LX 4-cyl 2.3L with 230k miles approximately on it. I try to take decent care but I've slipped up on oil a few times, always able to get another quart into it until I do a change.

My question is, I'm afraid there may be a leak. My last change was about 4 months ago and it's gone significantly down in oil level since then, down to 1 quart approximately. I've added 1 quart to satisfy the oil light until I change, but I needed advice on which weight and brand of oil to get, and what type of filter is a good recommended brand?

I'm also considering spark plugs, as I've not changed mine in about 4 years, though I don't know how big of a deal that is. It's been about 50k since I've replaced them.

I've got additional maintenance that'll be much, much more expensive in the future, but these are somethings I need to do right now. I'm sure transmission work and a new clutch are in the future. I love the car even though she's not that pretty in some spots, but no wrecks ever so I'd like to keep her for a while; car payments on a future vehicle scare me with my income level.

Comment: You might want to start with the owner's manual: http://owners.honda.com/vehicles/information/1998/Accord-Sedan/manuals

Comment: If it has lasted 230K whatever you have been doing thus far is working. I would check the oil level on a more frequent basis. Most oil lights won't come on until you are down two or more quarts. The closer you are to full the better.

Comment: It's actually been mine since 155k, prior owner used dealership for everything and I can't afford that so I'm trying to do all maintenance myself.

Answer (score 1):

**My question is, I'm afraid there may be a leak. My last change was about 4 months ago and it's gone significantly down in oil level since then, down to 1 quart approximately. I've added 1 quart to satisfy the oil light until I change, but I needed advice on which weight and brand of oil to get, and what type of filter is a good recommended brand?**

Have you tried checking underneath the car for fluid leaks? At 230,000 miles on a Honda, oil consumption is normal. I'd avoid synthetic on an older car. It tends to leak out faster.  I'd just use whatever is recommended in your manual.

**I'm also considering spark plugs, as I've not changed mine in about 4 years, though I don't know how big of a deal that is. It's been about 50k since I've replaced them.**

They might be like new or they could be shot. This depends several factors (running rich, excessive idling). Pulling plugs on a Honda is fairly easy. Here is an interesting article on spark plug wear (http://www.ngk.com.au/spark-plugs/technical-information/spark-plug-analysis). This can give you an idea on how your car is running as well.

**I've got additional maintenance that'll be much, much more expensive in the future, but these are somethings I need to do right now. I'm sure transmission work and a new clutch are in the future. I love the car even though she's not that pretty in some spots, but no wrecks ever so I'd like to keep her for a while; car payments on a future vehicle scare me with my income level.**

Has the timing belt & water pump been changed? This is very important.

What kind of transmission work are you referring to? Fluid change or a rebuild?